# Parallel stream - how much is parallel?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a parallel stream as shown in my `Runner.java` below. But I realize the aggregate method within the Runner class is running sequentially. I think this is because of the `forEach` I have and the loop cannot be broken althought I'm not sure. My analysis of this being sequential is based on the Thread name I'm printing within the getter method of the classes below.

Although the code below has a list of 1000 objects, to get smaller logs to be able to paste in here, I changed the list to 10 items to print the thread names. The logs are below after the `Runner.java`. Looking at them, the aggregate method is always executed by the main thread always and NOT by `CommonPool`. The same behavior is observed for 1000 items too. Could someone help me if the forEach is what is causing the sequential execution?

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
   private double salary;
   private String fName;
   private String lName;

   public Employee(double salary, String fName, String lName) {
      this.salary = salary;
      this.fName = fName;
      this.lName = lName;
   } 

   public Employee() {
   }

   public double getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary(double salary) {
     this.salary = salary;
   }

   public String getfName() {
      System.out.println("Thread.currentThread() + \"for getFname\" = " + Thread.currentThread() + 
     " for getFname");
      return fName;
   }

   public void setfName(String fName) {
      this.fName = fName;
   }

   public String getlName() {
       return lName;
   }

   public void setlName(String lName) {
       this.lName = lName;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "E{" +
            "s=" + salary +
            ", N='" + fName + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
  }
```

**Runner Class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(new Employee(i * 100, "A" + i, "Z" + i));

        }
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Employee> collect = list
                .parallelStream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getfName), Runner::aggregate));
        System.out.println("collect = " + collect.size());
        System.out.println(collect.stream().mapToDouble(e -> e.getSalary()).sum());
    }

    private static List<Employee> aggregate(Map<String, List<Employee>> t) {
        ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
        t.entrySet()
                .forEach(e -> {
                    System.out.println("Thread.currentThread() + \"within agrgate\" = " + Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate");
                    Employee e1 = new Employee();
                    e.getValue().forEach(r -> {
                        e1.setSalary(e1.getSalary() + r.getSalary());
                        e1.setfName(r.getfName());
                    });
                    emps.add(e1);
                });
        return emps;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
Thread.currentThread() + "within agrgate" = Thread[main,5,main]within agrgate
Thread.currentThread() + "for getFname" = Thread[main,5,main]for getFname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [for each](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) method is from the interface iterable, where "Actions are performed in the order of iteration..."

You can use the Stream for each then.

```
t.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach( e->{
```

Comment: A better approach is to let the `groupingBy` collector calculate the sum in the first place, instead of collection into lists and perform another form of reduction afterwards.